# Memory leak tool for C++ under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-leaks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

I need a recommendation of a free tool (even for a trial) for detecting memory leaks in C++ under Windows (Visual Studio 2005).

I've looked in the net, but I would prefer a recommendation.

Comment: marked as duplicate of a post which was deleted