# How to determine where a memory leak occurs in C++?

Tags: c++

How to determine where memory leak is, in C++ not by using any tools

I have a memory leak in my program, and I am trying to determine where it is leaking.

If you can shed any light on this subject please do.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502799/memory-leak-tool-for-c-under-windows Though you didn't specify which OS you're on.

Comment: Without tools? Exactly how without tools are you willing to go? :P

Comment: yes. without tools. Any idea?

Comment: Well what I mean is... you're going to have to use SOME tools. For example, your computer and it's OS, your compiler, perhaps an IDE? At what point will you stop using tools? For that matter, why eliminate tools? Code profiling and analysis tools are the tricks of the trade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the question (now) says "not using any tools", then you are probably reduced to looking at the source code.  One place to look is at the constructors and destructor of each class.

- Is all the memory allocated by your constructors released by your destructor?
- If other methods in your class allocate memory, is that memory released by your destructor?

Otherwise, look for instances of `new` (in all its varieties) and ensure you can establish where the allocated memory is released.

And, if you are misguided enough to mix C memory allocation via `malloc()`, `realloc()`, and `free()` in with your C++ code, then do a similar exercise on every allocation, ensuring you know where the corresponding release is.  (I assume that you would never attempt to `delete` space allocated by `malloc()` nor `free()` space allocated by `new`.)

Consider whether you should be using one of the various automatic pointer manager classes to ensure that memory is released.

You are probably better off using the tools available to highlight where the leaks occur.

Comment: Another important check: if any class is inheriting from another, does the parent class have a virtual destructor?  If not, the derived constructor may not be called, and any memory freed therein will leak.

Answer (score 1):

If you refuse to use other tools, you're pretty much stuck with the human eyeball, version 1.0. Unfortunately, unless the code is pretty trivial, this probably won't be easy. I don't mean to sound nasty saying it, but memory leaks are *incredibly* rare in well designed code. That means there's all too good a chance that the code you're working on has some fairly serious problems to start with, in which case finding leaks by inspection is more likely than not to be quite slow and painful.

The obvious starting points for the inspection would be all uses of `new`, `malloc`, `calloc`, etc., and (should-be) matching calls to `delete`, `free`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Profiling tools should be able to help.
For example:[valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Also, you can try to check all the warning messages from your compiler.

Edit: I missed the part about "without tools".

Checking compiler warnings I think is a good first step.

You can also try putting debug statements around all your free/delete code to make sure you are freeing something valid.

Look for common bugs like: "delete ptr" instead of "delete [] ptr".

Just do a grep/search for all the "new" and "delete" statements in your code and see if they make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() function of the crtdbg class

Comment: if not under Windows environment?