# C++ Memory Debugger?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, debugging

Can anyone recommend a quality C++ memory debugging API or software for Windows(specifically, one that works with MinGW)? I'm nearly positive there's a memory leak in my program, but I have no idea where to start looking.

Also, on a related note, I previously tried overloading the global new and delete operators myself, and storing debugging information from there. Yet, when I try to replace every occurrence of new with my overloaded operator, it throws a bunch of errors. I only tried using a simple preprocessor macro to do so.

```
#define new new(__FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Is there any distinct way around that problem?

EDIT: I probably should have been clearer with this. I did in fact declare an overload, and implemented it without any errors. The only problem was when I tried using a macro to replace all uses of the new operator to use my overload instead, which is why I only posted the macro code.

Comment: Of course your macro throws errors.  There is no overload of [operator new](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20new/) that takes those arguments.  Defining a macro doesn't just create an applicable function for you.

Comment: I don't want to sound condescending but the macro opens the way for a silly error: is your `new` defined *before* the macro appears? Why not ignore that altogether and define the global `new` (the one without arguments), doing the logging and getting the memory from e.g. `operator new`?

Comment: @Luc, nope. I made sure to add the declaration of my overload before the macro. Although, I may try just overloading the regular global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For memory leaks in Windows, I've found that UMDH with usermode stack traces enabled is pretty useful. [Here's a tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268343).

For a list of other tools, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502799/memory-leak-tool-for-c-under-windows).

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for, thanks. Hopefully it will help me uncover where the leak is coming from.