# Visual memory debugging application under Linux?

Tags: linux, debugging, cuda, gdb, cuda-gdb

Does there exist a debugging application similar to the [Visual Profiler for CUDA](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-visual-profiler)?  It shows information about the application at the function level in terms of execution time.  Is there something for regular C/C++ applications so I can see which functions are taking the most time and memory?

I'm trying to debug an application that reads in a lot of data files and uses a custom class to read the file and represent it internally as a vector of vectors.  I have another class which represents the operations performed on the data from the data file.  As I read more and more files in a loop and operate upon them, the memory usage just increases until the OS just kills the application.  I've been pretty good about cleaning up from using dynamic memory.  Something visual to help me wade through all the files and functions to see which use the most time and memory would be hugely beneficial!

I am able to use libproc from within my application to confirm that with each iteration of the loop, the memory usage goes from a cool ~500 megs to a whopping 19 GB.  This shouldn't be since the scope of the data is within the loop, so by the next iteration of the loop the C++ objects using the data should have been cleared and returned to the OS, but this isn't happening.

I hope this isn't too vague, and thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory leak tool for C++ under Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502799/memory-leak-tool-for-c-under-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Search for "c++ memory leak" on SO. See for instance: [Memory leak tool for C++ under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502799/memory-leak-tool-for-c-under-windows)

I'm guessing folks will close this as a duplicate.